# How to print a table's contents within a table? [Lua]

Tags: lua, lua-table

What I want to do is ONLY print a table's contents within a table. For example:

```
local stats = {
  table1 = {
    tTable1 = 
    {
      data = 1
    },
    tTable2 = 
    {
      data2 = 2
    },
    tTable3 =
    {
      data3 = 3
    },
  }
}
```

I don't really care about table1 or all the tTables but rather the information in the data variables. How can I print them?

This is a snippet of my real code:

```
local stats = {
  [1] = { 
    [1] = { 
      [1] = 1,
      [2] = -1,
      [3] = -1,
      ["n"] = 3,
    },
    [2] = { 
      [1] = nuclearcraft:cooler,
      [2] = 10,
      ["n"] = 2,
    },
    ["n"] = 2,
  },
  [2] = { 
    [1] = {
      [1] = 2,
      [2] = -1,
      [3] = -1,
      ["n"] = 3,
    },
    [2] = { 
      [1] = nuclearcraft:cell_block,
      [2] = 0,
      ["n"] = 2,
    },
    ["n"] = 2,
  },
  [3] = {
    [1] = {
      [1] = 3,
      [2] = -1,
      [3] = -1,
      ["n"] = 3,
    },
    [2] = { 
      [1] = nuclearcraft:cooler,
      [2] = 10,
      ["n"] = 2,
    },
    ["n"] = 2,
  },
}
```

This code actually goes on for a bit longer than this. In the real code, I don't care for any of the data except for the areas where it says "nuclearcraft" and the number beneath it.

Comment: It would depend exactly on the actual table. If the example is not the real table, can you post a sample of the real table? It would be hard and meticulous to index each value using stats.table1.tTable3.data3, but if they were all just 'data' you could use [pairs](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html) like this: `for key,value in pairs(stats.table1) do
print(value.data)
end` Better yet you could just leave out the key in the table declaration (`tTable1={1}`) if possible and do print(value[1]). Try it out https://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo

Comment: Yeah, for my example I used data1, data2, and data3 but I do have something similar to 'data' in my real table. As for an example of the real table, I am unable to do it now since I am on my phone. When I get back to my computer, I will be sure to try this!

Comment: I've added a snippet of my code.

Comment: Ok, so if you wanted to only get the second value of the second table in each larger table you could use a `for k,v in pairs(stats)` and print(v[2][2]). Here's some [code](https://pastebin.com/Z29wPtES) That should show you what I mean.

Comment: I actually changed the "pairs" into "ipairs" since the full table is an index-value table. Other than that, it seemed to have worked. I'm not sure if I can mark a comment as an answer, (I'm pretty new) but thank you!

Comment: Your real code does not compile: `nuclearcraft:cooler,` is a syntax error.

Comment: There are supposed to be quotation marks around them, I don't know why they were omitted when I pasted them in.

Answer (score 3):

recursive table traversal is suitable for this case:

```
local function TablePrint(t)
     for k,v in pairs(t)  do
         if type(v)=="table" then
            print(k)
            TablePrint(v)
         else 
            print('\t',k,v)
         end
     end      
end
TablePrint(stats)
```

result:

```
table1
tTable3
        data3   3
tTable2
        data2   2
tTable1
        data    1
```

keep in mind that the order of non-index values in the table is not defined