# Unable to Print Lua Table Key\Index & Values

Tags: lua, add-on, world-of-warcraft

A table received from a Gaming API (World of Warcraft) prints the following result as a whole

```
local sometbl = APICommand("args");
print(sometbl) --prints table: 000001F492F31....
```

basically some memory address I presume.

while trying either print(sometbl[1]) or print(sometbl[2]) the output is `nil`.

While trying

```
for key, value in next, sometbl do
    print(key .. " ".. value)
end
```

**OR**

```
for key, value in pairs(sometbl) do
    print(key .. " ".. value)
end
```

**OR**

```
for key, value in ipairs(sometbl) do
    print(key .. " ".. value)
end
```

No output is generated from any of these.

`the print(sometbl) still prints said memory reference`

How do can I print the entire contents of that peculiar table?

Comment: [maybe this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59515669/how-to-print-a-tables-contents-within-a-table-lua/59521445#59521445)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If

```
for key, value in pairs(sometbl) do
    print(key .. " ".. value)
end
```

prints nothing the table is empty. So there is no content to print.

`next(sometbl)` will return nil if the table is empty.

Comment: Wait, so an empty table will still output: table: 000001F492F31.... 
when trying to print(sometbl) ?

Comment: Printing a table value gives you something like "table: 0xa6f7b0"  that's a identifier for that table but of course a table may be empty.  Try `print{}` and see for yourself

Comment: ok, trying 
local emptyTable = {};
print(emptyTable) 
yields a similar result. Thanks @Piglet (lol, funny nick :P)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [/dump](https://wow.gamepedia.com/MACRO_dump) command too for easier inspecting of (empty) tables, e.g. `/dump APICommand("args")`